# Which app sent the unauthorized texts?

Tags: sms, logging, textsecure

Today I got an automated text from my wireless provider saying I'd gone over my text limit. This is odd because I send maybe 50 texts a month. When I logged into their customer site I found over 3000 photo texts had been sent in the last two days!

Some background: ever since the Kit Kat upgrade I'd had trouble with the stock messaging app so I test drove a couple of SMS apps before deciding on TextSecure. I've had it for the last few weeks and it seemed to be working fine. However after finding out about this problem I uninstalled that and went back to the stock app.

So the questions are: is there some way I can tell which app sent the rogue texts? The wireless provider's site lets me know the number that it sent to (a bogus number @icmms1.sun5.lightsurf.net) but not which app actually did the sending. I'm wondering if Android logs that somewhere. Also, is there a way to block *outgoing* texts?

Comment: Take a look in Settings -> Security under the "App Security" heading. There should be an "SMS message limit" option which will let you limit messages per app per 30 minutes. Not what you're looking for, but perhaps a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go through your apps list you can see all the apps that have permission to send texts (or you could use appops to save having to click on every app), you can then narrow it down based on how reputable the app is, and/or doing web searches, once you thing you have narrowed down the app you can either, uninstall the app or block the permission using app ops, however if it was text secure that was the offending app, then you wont be able to tell as it has already been uninstalled.

Comment: This sounded promising. Unfortunately when I went to read about it the appops developer said Google has made it so this app will not work on 4.4.2. Are you able to make it work?

Comment: I have root, so it does work, however you can always go through settings manually looking at each apps permissions

Comment: It sounds like there is no way to do exactly what I want, so giving you the credit for suggesting the best alternative strategy.